# How to access an element in a list?

Tags: elisp

I have this list:

```
("x" "y" "z")
```

How do I extract an element from the list? (In this case I'm interested in the first element in the list, but I'm looking for a general solution.)

Answer (score 18):

You really should read an intro to elisp or something before you try to use it. The Elisp manual which comes with Emacs in some distributions is quite good.

```
(nth 0 mylist)
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html

Comment: And you should accept an answer when it is provided. In this case, @triplee's answer is fine, assuming you know the list position of the element.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the list position of the element, then use `(nth 0 mylist)`, as @triplee indicated.

If you want to test element equality (in this case, string equality) then use this:

```
    (car (member "y" mylist))
```

`(member "y" mylist)` returns the sublist (tail) `("y" "z")`, and `car` returns the first element of that sublist (`car` is the same as `nth` with `0` first arg).

If the string you want is not a member of the list, then `member` returns the empty list `nil` (aka `()`), and `car` of that list returns `nil`.  So `member` is both (a) a *predicate* for testing list membership (returns `nil' for not present and non-`nil` for present) and (b) a way to extract the first sublist (tail) that contains the element you seek.

Answer (score 0):

Read subsections [List Elements](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html#List-Elements) and [Using Lists as Sets](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sets-And-Lists.html#Sets-And-Lists) of section [Lists](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lists.html#Lists) of [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html). The manual is your friend, it's the first place you should look, when you have a question about Elisp. To access the manual inside Emacs, view it using Info system by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>`elisp`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, or navigate around Info-mode manually.

If you write serious Elisp code, I recommend installing [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) package, which has plenty of functions to query and transform lists. For example, if you want to find a first (or last) element that satisfies a predicate, use [`-first`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-first-pred-list) or [`-last`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-last-pred-list):

```
(-first 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ; 2
(-last 'evenp '(1 2 3 4 5 6)) ; 6
```